# HTML form validation with JavaScript (phone number format condition)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have one phone number field when a user enter/paste 13 digits (ex. +913456789054) phone number then the first 3 digits should be deleted and the remaining 10 digits (3456789054) should be assigned to a variable. The same for 12 digits number (913456789054) should be deleted the first 2 digits and only assign the remaining 10 digits (3456789054)...

How to write this kind of condition in JavaScript?

Here is code, now I want to add phone number validation…

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("send__btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    var userValue = document.getElementById("user_value").value;
    var uesrMessage = document.getElementById("uesr_message").value;
    var send_message =
      "https://example.com/send?phone=+91" +
      userValue;
    window.open(send_message, "_self");
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form name="textform">
    <input
      type="number"
      name="mobiNumber"
      id="user_value"
      class="user__value"
      placeholder="Enter number"
      pattern="\d*"
      maxlength="13"
    />
    <div class="btn">
      <button id="send__btn" type="submit" value="Submit">Send
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: What have you tried to far? What problems did you face?

Comment: Can you please share some code? So that we can see what you have tried so far.

Comment: actually i don't know how to write this kind of validation

Comment: @VickyPawar It's extremely simple, what don't you know?

Comment: post updated check now

Comment: So you just want to get the last 10 characters from a string? `var newstring = string.length > 10 ? string.substring(string.length - 10) : string;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var numberPlus = "+913456789054";
var numberNoPlus = "913456789054";

function removePrefix (number) {
    if (number.startsWith('+')) {
        return number.substring(3);
    } else {
        return number.substring(2);
    }
}

console.log("Without plus: " + removePrefix(numberNoPlus));
console.log("With plus: " + removePrefix(numberPlus));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var number = "918877665544";
    var final_number;
    if (number.indexOf("+91") == 0) {
        final_number = number.replace("+91", "");
    }else if (number.indexOf("91") == 0) {
        final_number = number.replace("91", "");
    }

    console.log(final_number);
```

Comment: You can use `.startsWith()`